# Is it possible to get binary count from Counter() Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, counter, python-itertools

Using `Counter()`, I want to do a binary count of variables in a list. So instead of getting the count for each variable, I would simply like to have a `Counter()` variable, in which all values are one.

So for a given list:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,62,3,4,5,1]
```

I want the output to be:

```
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 62: 1})
```

Instead of:

```
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 62: 1})
```

I am aware that I could loop through the Counter:

```
binary_count = {x: 1 for x in Counter(data)}
```

However, that does require looping through the dictionary once and seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't what a `Counter` is for, so whatever you do will require modifying the output.

Why not just not use a `Counter` to begin with? This should be trivial with a regular `dict`.

Heck, you can even just use `dict.fromkeys`, so:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5,62,3,4,5,1]
>>> dict.fromkeys(data, 1)
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 62: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this `dict` option

Comment: @Emil If the values aren't important, you could even consider using a `set`, which is similar to a dict without values.